# How pipeline execution time had been calculated in the official guide?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to understand how the price estimation works for Azure Data Factory from the official guide, section "Estimating Price - [Use Azure Data Factory to migrate data from Amazon S3 to Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-migration-guidance-s3-azure-storage)

I managed to understand everything except the 292 hours that are required to complete the migration.

Could you please explain to me how did they get that number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, feel free to submit a feedback [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/new) with the MS docs team to clarify with an official response on same.

> [image]

Meanwhile, I see, as they mention *"**In total**, it takes 292 hours to **complete  the migration**"* it would include listing from source, reading from source, writing to sink, other activities, other than the data movement itself.

If we consider approximately, for data volume of 2 PB and aggregate throughput of 2 GBps would give

> 2PB = 2,097,152 GB BINARY and
> Aggregate throughput =
> 2BGps --> 2,097,152/2 = 1,048,576 secs --> 1,048,576 secs / 3600 =
> 291.271 hours

Again, these are hypothetical. Further you can refer [Plan to manage costs for Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/plan-manage-costs) and [Understanding Data Factory pricing through examples.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/pricing-concepts#copy-data-from-aws-s3-to-azure-blob-storage-hourly)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply! May I please check with you how did you get 277 hours in your estimation. Per my calculation, 2 Gbps is about 250 MB per second or 1 GB per 4 seconds. 2 PB is 2 097 152 GB. Thus, 2 097 152 * 4 (total time to transfer) / 3600 (seconds in an hour) = 2330 hours, which is about 97 days or around 3.2 month. This number is quite close to another MS guide - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance

Comment: 2PB = 2,097,152 GB BINARY and as they mention, Aggregate throughput =  2BGps --> 2,097,152/2 = 1,048,576 secs  --> 1,048,576 secs / 3600 = 291.271 hours

Comment: 2 PB = 2,000,000 GB in DECIMAL --> which for same above calculation gives 277.777 hours

Comment: @ KarthikBhyresh-MT Got it about binary / decimal, but I still have a question. One clarification on 2 GBps, do you want to say that's Gigabytes per second? In the documentation, it's stated that "Migrating data over HTTPS using first solution architecture", which is data transfer via internet. As far as I understand, this speed isn't achievable if you are transferring data via the public network. if we assume that's Gbps then the number should be multiplied by 4.

Comment: correct, Gbps --> "Gigabits per second". Ah, yea hypothetical example as they say, but why multiply by 4.

Comment: That's a hypothetical example, because a hypothetical example should be possible in real world. The example in the guide is totally misleading (I'm using it to estimate costs for data migration excesses) and impossible in real world. It's necessary to multiply data amount in GB by 4 because with speed of 2 Gbps per second one GB will be transferred in 4 seconds.

Comment: maybe you should submit a feedback to get an official response

Comment: If the answer was any helpful , You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Comment: accepted your answer, thank you for your help! Going to submit a feedback and see a reply from the Azure team